# FileNotFoundError: Model does not exist. Check your path and try again

Tags: python

i am trying to create a project folder for my results to be sent with this code:

```
fldr = 'D:/release/Sample models/sioux_falls_2020_02_15'
proj_name = 'SiouxFalls.sqlite'

dt_fldr = '0_tntp_data' #*
prj_fldr = '1_project' #*
skm_fldr = '2_skim_results' #*
assg_fldr = '4_assignment_results' #*
dstr_fldr = '5_distribution_results' #*
frcst_fldr = '6_forecast' #*
ftr_fldr = '7_future_year_assignment' #*

p = Parameters() #*
p.parameters['system']['logging_directory'] = fldr #*
p.write_back() #*

# We the project open, we can tell the logger to direct all messages to the terminal as well
stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s;%(name)s;%(levelname)s ; %(message)s")
stdout_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)

############# PROJECT########## *
project = Project() #*
project.load(join(fldr, prj_fldr, proj_name)) #*
```

however, I am receiving this error in my terminal:

```
  File "test1.py", line 63, in <module>
    project.load(join(fldr, prj_fldr, proj_name)) #*
  File "/home/karabo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aequilibrae/project/project.py", line 119, in load
    self.open(project_path)
  File "/home/karabo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aequilibrae/project/project.py", line 57, in open
    raise FileNotFoundError("Model does not exist. Check your path and try again")
FileNotFoundError: Model does not exist. Check your path and try again
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Error is self descriptive. Please show your actual folder structure

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the path needs to be set to the folder where the project database is, as AequilibraE projects are a set of files inside a folder (Example in the [documentation](http://aequilibrae.com/python/latest/_auto_examples/plot_forecasting.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-forecasting-py).
So I suspect the appropriate code would be:

```
fldr = 'D:/release/Sample models/sioux_falls_2020_02_15'

project = Project()
project.load(fldr)
```

Disclosure: I am the creator of the AequilibraE package.